# Python: object as an argument of another object

Tags: python, class, object, arguments

I have a module including definitions for two different classes in Python. How do I use objects of one class as an argument of the other? Say, I have class definitions for Driver and Car, and tuen want to have a Driver object as an argument for a Car object.

Comment: Define "argument". Functions have arguments, classes don't.

Comment: Can you post sample code? It is not clear why you are trying to say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: The OP is trying to pass an object instance at class definition time (or so I think after seeing his comment). The answer below is not applicable.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

class Driver:
    pass

driver = Driver()
car = Car(driver)
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do: pass an object instance at class definition time

Comment: Ah. Can you tell me how you are using that object instance in the class definition? Your comment above seems to use it in the class *constructor*, which doesn't make much sense. Posting some code would help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of a Driver object and pass it to the Car's constructor.

e.g.,

```
>>> d = Driver()
>>> c = Car(d)
```

or just

```
>>> c = Car(Driver())
```

[edit]

So you're trying to use an instance of a driver as you define a class?  I'm still not sure I understand what it is you're trying to do but it sounds like some kind of decorator perhaps.

```
def OwnedCar(driver):
    class Car(object):
        owner = driver
        #...
    return Car

steve = Driver()
SteveCar = OwnedCar(steve)
```

Comment: My question was a bit unclear, what I mean is how to handle object argument in the class definition:

    class Car:
      def __init__(self, driverA)
      driverA.foo()
      driverA.bar()

Does this work, or do I have to define the type of Driver in the class definitions?

Comment: @rize In python you try it and see if it works. to answer your question, no you do not need to define the type of the argument `DriverA`. If `DriverA.foo` and `DriverA.bar` exist, then there will be no error. You could pass it a `Pilot` as long as `Pilot.foo` and `Pilot.bar` exist and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this will help you
Assume we have 
class BankAccount:
   '''After Constructor, we have another method '''
   def transfer(self,amount,object): #object is variable passed  for referencing an object
       BankAccount.credit(self,amount)
       object.debit(amount)

call method
bank1=BankAccount()
bank1.transfer(2000,objectname)